# Compound literal for two-dimensional array of strings

Tags: arrays, c, c99, compound-literals

I have a two-dimensional array of strings inside a struct, and I'd like to be able to initialize it at compile time, with a compound literal, rather than dynamically with malloc().

The meaning of this array of strings is that it's an array of items, with each item having three strings (one for the name of the item, another for a description, and another for a URL).

Yes, I know I could use three arrays instead, but I'd prefer to pack it in a two-dimensional array.

I tried to write it this way (NOTE that I'm initializing just the name of the item, but not the description nor the URL... this is on purpose, as I assume the pointers to the description and the URL will be automatically initialized to NULL according to the designated initializers behaviour --when you don't initialize a field, it becomes zero)

My attempt:

```
enum labelkind {
    L_NAME,
    L_DESCRIPTION,
    L_URL,
    L_NUMKINDS};
    
struct labeltype{
    int someval;
    size_t  nlabels;
    char    **labels[L_NUMKINDS];
    };
    
static struct labeltype mylabel = {
    .someval=10,
    .nlabels=3,
    .labels=(char *[][L_NUMKINDS]){
        [0][L_NAME]="First name",
        [1][L_NAME]="Second name",
        [2][L_NAME]="Third name"
        }
    };
```

Compiling it with clang, I get these warnings:

```
main.c:266:10: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'char **' with an expression of type 'char *[3][3]'
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        .labels=(char *[][L_NUMKINDS]){
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:266:10: warning: suggest braces around initialization of subobject [-Wmissing-braces]
        .labels=(char *[][L_NUMKINDS]){
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                {
```

So, from these warnings, I guess I'm doing something wrong.

What would be the correct syntax for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure definition is incorrect: as defined, `labels` is an array of `L_NUMKINDS` pointers to pointers to `char`. You probably want `labels` to point to an array of `nlabels` arrays of `L_NUMKINDS` pointers to `char`. The definition should be `char *(*labels)[L_NUMKINDS];` or better `const char *(*labels)[L_NUMKINDS];` since you want to use string constants as initializers.

Here is a modified version with a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum labelkind {
    L_NAME,
    L_DESCRIPTION,
    L_URL,
    L_NUMKINDS
};

struct labeltype {
    int someval;
    size_t nlabels;
    const char *(*labels)[L_NUMKINDS];
};

static struct labeltype mylabel = {
    .someval = 10,
    .nlabels = 4,
    .labels = (const char *[][L_NUMKINDS]) {
        [0][L_NAME] = "First name",
        [1][L_NAME] = "Second name",
        [2][L_NAME] = "Third name",
        [3][L_NAME] = "Fourth name",
    }
};

static void pstr(const char *name, const char *s) {
    printf("%s: ", name);
    if (s)
        printf("\"%s\"", s);
    else
        printf("null");
}

static void print_labels(const struct labeltype *lp) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lp->nlabels; i++) {
        printf("{ ");
        pstr("name", lp->labels[i][L_NAME]);
        printf(", ");
        pstr("description", lp->labels[i][L_DESCRIPTION]);
        printf(", ");
        pstr("url", lp->labels[i][L_URL]);
        printf(" }\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    print_labels(&mylabel);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
{ name: "First name", description: null, url: null }
{ name: "Second name", description: null, url: null }
{ name: "Third name", description: null, url: null }
{ name: "Fourth name", description: null, url: null }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @chqrlie. What I want to do is a two-dimensional array of Nx3 strings, so it's either `char **[3]` or `char *[][3]` . Your code is a one-dimensional array of strings, I need two-dimensional.

Comment: @cesss: the definition should actually be `const char *(*labels)[L_NUMKINDS];` and the compound literal should read as `(const char *[][L_NUMKINDS]) { ... }`

Comment: That's it, @chqrlie! The parentheses! I'm afraid I need to practice with the `dcl` tool from the K&R book!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have been practicing C definitions for close to 40 years now, including implementing parsers and compilers and it still bites me. The C99 constructions increased the complexity for little gain and much implementors' pain. Keep a good mood and enjoy the trip :)

Comment: Try parsing C definitions using the spiral rule: from the identifier, parse to the right, when you hit a `)` parenthesis, parse to the left of the identifier, when you hit a `(` skip the `()` and parse to the right, etc.  `const char *(*labels)[L_NUMKINDS];` is a pointer to array**s** of `L_NUMKINDS` string pointers.